# What's the result of point's projection method using the RGeo::Geographic.simple_mercator_factory

Tags: postgis, rgeo

I have a factory `RGEO_FACTORY = RGeo::Geographic.simple_mercator_factory`

And I have a point(POINT (28.97566007 41.01452809)), whose srid is 3785.

Then I get a new coordinate using `RGEO_FACTORY.point(lon, lat).projection`. And it's `POINT (3225555.7243913896 5014484.790030423)`

Now, I need to use the sql to query to improve the speed. Like this:`"SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Transform(lat_lon, 4326)) from points WHERE points.id = 1"` . I expect to get the same result as `POINT (3225555.7243913896 5014484.790030423)`. But I can't get it.

And I have tried other srid to transform the coordinate of the point, but in vain.

What should I do to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -2):

When you use `RGeo::Geographic.simple_mercator_factory` to create points, like you do with `RGEO_FACTORY.point(lon, lat)`, their srid is predefined by the factory, and it's not 3785, it's 4326, see [the docs](http://rubydoc.info/github/dazuma/rgeo/master/RGeo/Geographic.simple_mercator_factory) for yourself. And these points' `projection` method returns points in 3785. Learn the actual srid of your lat_lon field with ST_SRID(lat_lon), if it's a geometry type, then figure out which srid you want to covert it to.

Covered that in more details answering [another similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14064107/how-to-express-the-projection-using-pure-sql/15366393#15366393).